# Is it Possible to restrict MySQL View Update?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table named myTable in MySQL. The myTable records will be truncated or inserted by some jobs. I want to create a View from myTable. But the view shouldn't get updated if myTable records are deleted or truncated. The View should refresh only if there is any insert in myTable.  I am not sure if this is doable. Please advice.

Comment: Share codes about what you have try and what you get an error and what you expecting as output.

Comment: View in MySQL is completely dynamic, it uses source data in those state which was stored at the view execution moment. After receiving the view result is not linked to the source data, and it cannot be refreshed, the view re-quering is the only option. And MySQL have no data changing announcement service - you must check the data for does it was altered. You may simplify this with a trigger which saves last data change timestamp to some service table.